# Unable to open database connection from configuration value

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Firstly I am aware that this has been asked many times, but I could not find anything related to my problem specifically. basically I have text inputs I need to insert into a local DB, I've checked my connection string many times, and pretty certain it isn't the problem.

```
<add name="ElectricsOnline" 
     connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\electricsonline.mdf;Integrated Security=True" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

and here is the method for inserting

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection("ElectricsOnline"))
        {
            connection.Open();

            var sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO Orders (FirstName, LastName, Phone, Address, Suburb, State, Postcode, Ctype, CardNo, ExpDate, Email) VALUES(@FirstName, @LastName, @Phone, @Address, @Suburb, @State, @Postcode, @Ctype, @CardNo, @ExpDate, @Email)";

            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, connection))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtFirstname.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtLastname.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", txtPhone.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txtAddress.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Suburb", txtSuburb.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", txtState.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Postcode", txtPostcode.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ctype", ddlCtype.SelectedValue.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CardNo", txtCardno.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExpDate", txtExpDate.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

        Response.Redirect("CheckoutReview.aspx");
    }
```

Source error shows this

> Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.
>
> Line 22:         {
>   Line 23:
>   Line 24:             using (var connection = new SqlConnection("ElectricsOnline"))
>   Line 25:             {
>   Line 26:                 connection.Open();

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Can you post the actual exception message?

Comment: Try to explicitly (in code) assign the connection string to your connection

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use the *name* of your connection from configuration file directly, because `new SqlConnection(...)` needs a connection string itself, not its name from the config file.

You need to retrieve connection string from config before using it to create connections. Change your code as follows:

```
var connStr = System
    .Configuration
    .ConfigurationManager
    .ConnectionStrings["ElectricsOnline"]
    .ConnectionString;
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connStr)) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
new SqlConnection("ElectricsOnline")
```

I don't know where you got the idea that you could pass in the name of a configuration value. You need to pass in **the connection string**. Read it from your configuration and pass it to the constructor.

Comment: _"I don't know where you got the idea that you could pass in the name of a configuration value."_ - Entity Framework? Its DbContext has a constructor parameter named `nameOrConnectionString`.

Comment: @CodeCaster Considering this was wrongly tagged EntityFramework, maybe you are right.